# save time into SQL Database

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, database

I have a SQL Database with the following structure:
[image: Databank Structure:]

I have 4 `MaskedTextBox` for:

```
       (Structure)
       DateFrom: 0000.00.00
       DateFromTime: 00:00:00
       DateTo: 0000.00.00
       DateToTime: 00:00:00
```

.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TABELLE2 (MessageHeadline, MessageText,  SpecifyUser, CreateDate, CreateTime, CreateUser, DateFrom, DateFromTime, DateTo, DateToTime) VALUES (@MessageHeadline, @MessageText, @SpecifyUser, @CreateDate, @CreateTime, @CreateUser, @DateFrom, @DateFromTime, @DateTo, @DateToTime)");
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Connection = connection;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MessageHeadline", TB_MSGHeadline.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MessageText", TB_MSGText.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SpecifyUser", TB_SpecifyUser.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreateDate", CreateDate );
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreateTime", CreateTime);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreateUser", CreateUser);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateFrom", MTB_DateFrom.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateFromTime", MTB_DateFromTime.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTo", MTB_DateTo.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateToTime", MTB_DateToTime.Text);
                    connection.Open();

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    TB_MSGHeadline.Clear();
                    TB_MSGText.Clear();
                    TB_SpecifyUser.Clear();
```

And finally I want to save these values from my `MasketTextBox` into my database to use them later.

[image]

I try to change the Structure and try some SQL Date/Time formation but i get the error:

Comment: Why do you split Date and Time?

Comment: I have to check them seperated @Alexander

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing the `DATE` parameters in the incorrect format.  You need to pass them as a valid `DateTime` which your MaskedTextBox values do not appear to be.

For example, `@DateFrom` is a `SQL Date` data type.  You should pass it a valid parameter such as a `DateTime`:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateFrom", DateTime.Now);
```

You may need to parse the MaskedTextBox values correct using `DateTime.TryParse`

```
DateTime parsedDate;
bool success = DateTime.TryParse(MaskedInputOne.Text, out parsedDate);

if (success) {
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateFrom", parsedDate);
}
```

In this case we are only adding the parameter if the conversion succeeds.

Comment: Thank you! Work perfect ... i split it now up into Date/Time for To and From and it write it perfect into my databse ... :)

Do you have a Code example to check the Date, so it can't be in the past?

Comment: @Karl-Heinz - Glad to help.  That is a new question, you should post another question regarding this.

Comment: I will try to solve this and if i have some Problem i will create a new Question :) 
Thanks ^^